# How to get access to the MainWindow viewmodel from Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm trying to understand binding system in WPF. In my example i need to get access to MainWindow viewmodel from Page in XAML.

I have one solution to implement this. But i want to know more different ways

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="FunAnkiWPF.MainWindow"
    ...omitted for brevity
    Height="450" Width="800"
    DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
Self}}">
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(this);
        InitializeComponent();            
    }    
}
```

**StartPage.xaml** (**usual page**)

**StartPage.xaml.cs** (**One solution that works**)

```
public partial class StartPage : Page
{
    public StartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext;
    }
}
```

How to get a direct access to the MainWindow ViewModel property (in XAML and in codebehind)?
How to get access to another datacontext in XAML (like in my StartPage codebehind)?

Comment: If the page is in the visual tree of the MainWindow, it is not neccessary at all to set the DataContext explicitely as it will be inherited. If not, you may want to think over your concept again as it introduces a tight coupling.

Comment: @KlausGütter In **MainWindow.xaml** this is implemented like this:
        <Grid >
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Content="{Binding CurrentPage, 
                      Converter={local:ApplicationPageValueConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>

Comment: Do not use pages. Do not use Frame. Host UserControl in a ContentControl instead. Look up viewmodel first. And you can use relativesource to get to the datacontext of a parent window

Comment: @Andy I watched YouTube video and tried to implement my own application like in video. That’s why I choose pages

Comment: Unless you're really going to use the journal of the frame they're just a memory overhead. Which can be substantial BTW.  There's also subtle gotchas lurking in them can trip you up. I've never seen a commercial app uses pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to binding from a child control to a property in the parent window's datacontext is relativesource eg:

```
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.MainWinVMString, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

Here's an example to give you the flavour of what I am suggesting.

The MainWindow markup is a bit quick n dirty.
I would put datatemplates in a resource dictionary merged by app.xaml.

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}">
        <local:LoginUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}">
        <local:UserUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationViewModelTypes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding VMType}"
                />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"
                    />
</Grid>
```

Viewmodel for that:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string MainWinVMString { get; set; } = "Hello from MainWindoViewModel";

    public ObservableCollection<TypeAndDisplay> NavigationViewModelTypes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TypeAndDisplay>
        (
        new List<TypeAndDisplay>
        {
           new TypeAndDisplay{ Name="Log In", VMType= typeof(LoginViewModel) },
           new TypeAndDisplay{ Name="User", VMType= typeof(UserViewModel) }
        }
        );

    private object currentViewModel;

    public object CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return currentViewModel; }
        set { currentViewModel = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private RelayCommand<Type> navigateCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Type> NavigateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return navigateCommand
              ?? (navigateCommand = new RelayCommand<Type>(
                vmType =>
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = null;
                    CurrentViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(vmType);
                }));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Relaycommand is from nuget package mvvmlightlibs.

UserUC:

```
<Grid Background="pink">
    <TextBlock Text="This is the User module Control"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.MainWinVMString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               />
</Grid>
```

Full working sample:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmPvL3r385QhgqIZUul-ppiIHZ9uyA